# How to check who owns the Slack's workspace?

Tags: slack, domain

I'd like to check who owns (or at least some kind of public profile page) some workspace based on its subdomain (e.g. `xyz.slack.com`).

Is it possible?

Comment: Hopefully not, that would be a privacy violation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That information is private and access to it is reserved for members of the workspace.

So if you're a member of the workspace you can find out who the workspace owner is here: https://my.slack.com/account/team

If you aren't a member of the workspace, that information is not available to you.

Comment: Darn, this kinda stinks. Someone took our company name's slack name, and we are unsure who hehe (too many employees to ask and might have been old employee with a now invalid email). Would be nice if they could say like "h***@ourcompany.com owns ourcompany.slack.com" so we can try to figure out which user, or they can contact that user on our behalf (and we'll setup an email firewall rule to forward all slack emails temporarily to the sys-admin so we can figure out who owns it, in case its an old user [well guess that would work only if someone at @ourcompany.com owns the url hehe]).